# VBA: Convert all column data from formula to value based on whether they have data in them?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet for our bi-weekly payroll that has an INDEX MATCH formula that pulls an employee's pay based on the pay cycle and of course their position number. I am hoping I could run a macro which would convert the formulas into values once those bi-weekly salaries show up on the table as the year progresses.

Essentially, I don't want the columns shaded in blue's formulas be overwritten when I run this code. I've tracked some threads for formulas where it will do that for the entire workbook/sheet, but I'm at a loss for this specific need.

Example

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how one way to solve this.

Your info was a bit scant, so I've made various assumptions.
These are explained in the example worksheet and vba code.

**Workbook explained** (for future reference)
[image: Snapshot of sheet]

**The vba code**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertToValues()

''' Assume table isn't massive and use integers for row numbers
    Dim inC%, inR%, inCountEmpty%, inDataRows%

''' Assume sheet with the target table is the currently active sheet.
    With ActiveSheet.Range("wstEmpPays")
        
    ''' Based on the defined and bordered name-range:
    ''' o  Number of data rows is total rows less heading and top and bottom border rows
        inDataRows = .Rows.Count - 3
        
    ''' Based on the defined and bordered name-range:
    ''' o  Look in column 3+ and rows 3 to last-1 (i.e. the data area, excluding the table headings)
    ''' o  Covert all formulas to values, stopping at first 'all empty' column
        For inC = 3 To .Columns.Count

        ''' Ignore columns already converted (i.e. has a value, not formula, in the first data cell)
            If Not .Cells(3, inC).HasFormula Then GoTo procNxtC
            
        ''' NOTE: Here I'm testing for your 'no-value found' returning "" (zero lengths string)
        ''' o  Change this if 'nothing' is represented by some other value
            inCountEmpty = 0
            For inR = 3 To .Rows.Count - 1
                If .Cells(inR, inC) = "" Then inCountEmpty = inCountEmpty + 1
            Next inR
            
        ''' If all data cells are nothing: End now (1st 'all empty' column found)
            If inCountEmpty = inDataRows Then Exit For
            
        ''' Otherwise: Convert data columns to values
            For inR = 3 To .Rows.Count - 1
                .Cells(inR, inC) = .Cells(inR, inC)
            Next inR
                    
        ''' Step to next column
procNxtC: Next inC
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This would be no use to anyone coming along after you've removed the file, so maybe better as a comment.

Comment: Yeah, ok. Kind of figured it was one-time use thing and doing it in an actual book was much simpler than trying to explain it all. Is it possible to upload files to here somehow (as I couldn't find a way)? If not, once the author is sorted (or perhaps before), I'll break it out into a detailed post.

Comment: Have now done that. But will still leave the actual file up for a week, to allow the author to access should they wish.

Comment: @Spinner - My sincerest apologies for the lack of info on my part. I've downloaded the file, so please feel free to take it down. The scenarios you've assumed are all correct and the code works perfectly - thank you!!! I've only started dabbling in vba and the comments you added helps a ton in my learning.

Comment: Good oh.  Now, for your part, perhaps you could tick this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Dim col As Range

For Each col In ActiveSheet.Range("C4:F12").Columns 'adjust range as needed
    'column contains at least one number, and first cell has a formula
    If Application.Count(col) > 0 And col.Cells(1).HasFormula Then
        col.Value = col.Value 'remove any formulas
    End If
Next col
```